# What does a NET 30 salary mean?

Tags: salary, united-states, internship

I'm currently on an internship, where I have to send out invoices at the end of every week. After 1 month and  a week of working, I finally receive my first cheque payment, however only received my first week's worth of salary. Does that mean I would only get paid a week's worth of payment after 30 days of each weekly invoice? I thought it's going to be the accumulated amount by the end of the month.

Comment: I have only heard that term as it applies to payment of a contractor, but maybe it applies to interns too.  Need to ask your HR contact or manager.

Comment: In purchasing it can mean you don't get paid for 30 days.  But for that to apply to an intern is odd to me.

Comment: It shouldn't apply to payment to employees.  It makes no sense because you are already working before you get paid.  If there are problems with your work, you fire the guy or talk to him or whatever.  Withholding pay is **not** an option if the work is done properly.  Delaying wage makes no sense.

Comment: Did they explicitly state Net 30 or is that your inference?

Comment: **Talk to the person managing payroll first**. We can only guess at what's going on and those questions don't make for good Q&A. If you're not sure how to address that topic with HR/whoever, *that* is a question we can help with, please [edit] your question in that case.

Comment: Are you working in an actual office or is this remote? This doesn't sound like an internship (at least in the US). Something seems wrong with this situation based on your description.

Comment: I downvoted this because (a) it's something very specific to you / your company, (b) it's something you should discuss with your manager (strangers on the internet are unlikely to be able to help) and (c) it's unlikely to be useful to other people.

Comment: If you have to invoice it, it´s not salary, and you are not an intern but a contractor. Have a look at the [Freelance-Stack](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It probably means that you will get paid within 30 days of when you invoiced them. So if you sent out an invoice on January 1, you should get paid for whatever was on that invoice sometime around January 31.

Answer (score 3):

This is not normal.

NET 30 terminology is for [invoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_D).  This is simply a grace period to factor in confirming shipment quality, shipping, and various logistical issues involved in B2B transactions of large amount of goods.

However, this may be illegal as an employer paying their staff, contractor or not.

Contact your HR and see what's going on with your paycheck.  If this is a one time occurrence, you can just let it slide.  If they somehow justify delaying another 30 days for your wages (you are already working before you get paid, and now they're delaying it another 30), start looking at legal resources.

http://employment.findlaw.com/wages-and-benefits/payday-laws-overview.html

Comment: I do agree it's illegal for an employee but why would it be illegal for a contractor?  Contractors are basically vendors.

Comment: It is illegal because the contract does not allow it. If you sign a contract to pay you June 1, being paid on July 1 is a breach of contract. If the employer wants to pay you July 1, just sign for that! Don't put down "June 1, Net 30".

Comment: June 1, Net 30 doesn't mean you'll be paid on July 1.  I'm currently a 1099, on Net-30 terms--in practice I'm paid as part of the next payroll run after I submit an invoice.  I've gotten checks in the first week of the month, I've gotten checks in the 4th week.

Comment: @Nelson - I suspect that you lack the expertise in consulting to provide a quality answer to this question.

Comment: This is not the OP submitting invoices to their clients.  I realize if you setup invoicing for your clients, then yes, you can do NET-D payment types.  However, the OP sends out invoices, based on my understanding, as **part of their job**, which then the employer fails to pay for an extra 30 days.  I've never heard of a self-employed consulting intern before, but I may be wrong.